# Can't create a FOREIGN KEY MySQL error 150

Tags: mysql

I'm heaving a problem with adding a foreign key on table `votes`.

```
mysql> describe votes;
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id  | int(11) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| video_id | int(11) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| vote     | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> describe user;
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| email    | varchar(256)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| password | varchar(32)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| name     | varchar(24)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Votes.user_id is a foreign key to User.id. Bot have the same time however when I run:

```
mysql> alter table `votes` 
       add CONSTRAINT `votes_FK_1` 
       FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`);
```

MySQL is throwing a good old 150

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'crocko.#sql-6e1_3c5' (errno: 150)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have stored data on the tables already?

Comment: Was your DB is in  MYISAM engine?

Comment: Thank you Stranger - that exactly what is was. Changed to innodb and now it's fine.

Comment: Tat's good :) Sorry couldn able answer to you unavoidable interuption:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check whether you have any data stored in your table.. If yes, then you need to remove them..

Or, If your MySQL DB Engine is **MyISAM**, you won't be able to add foreign key after table is created..

You can check how to change it to **InnoDB**..

Comment: That's what it was - some tables where MyISAM and some where InnoDB. Thank you for the help.